# Error when using EXIT_FAILURE C++ "could not convert '1' from int to std::vector<double>"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I wrote a simple code that does the subtraction of two vectors, and when I want to return "EXIT_FAILURE" in an "if condition", I have an error saying "could not convert '1' from int to std::vector". In my code I included "cstdlib.h" where EXIT_FAILURE is defined, here's my code (which is developed in the IDE Eclipse):

```
std::vector<double> subtract_two_vectors(std::vector<double> const
&vect1,std::vector<double> const &vect2)
{
  //the second vector is subtracted from the first one
  int size_vect1 = vect1.size();
  int size_vect2 = vect2.size();

  if(size_vect1!=size_vect2)
  {
      printf("Error, The vectors to subtract should have the size size \n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

 //declare the vector to be filled and returned afterwards
 std::vector<double> result(size_vect1);
 for(int i=0;i<size_vect1;i++)
 {
     result[i]=vect1[i]-vect2[i];
 }

  return result;
}
```

I don't know why I have this error, because I have a C code where I did the exact same thing and I didn't have this error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: _I have a C code where I did the exact same thing_ you have a function in C, that returns a std::vector?

Comment: That is no way you have a C code doing the same thing because C does not have vectors. Maybe you intended to actually exit program instead of returning error code (this is not `main` function to do so)? Then you should write `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: @manni66 what I meant by "I did the exact same thing" is that in my C code instead of using vectors I used a pointer on an array and my function returns a (double *array). So when I used return EXIT_FAILURE in an if condition it didn't cause any probems.

Comment: @VTT I commented on my C code above. I tried  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); but I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is of type `std::vector<double>` and you are trying to return a [EXIT_FAILURE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) macro that is of type `int`. Either modify the function to be of type `int`, throw an exception or return an empty vector:

```
return std::vector<double>{};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you wanted is

```
std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

@Ron correctly told what is the problem.

---

Now, let me present more or less C++ solution.

```
std::vector<double> substract_two_vectors(std::vector<double> const &lhs,
                                          std::vector<double> const &rhs)
{
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"vectors must be of equal sizes"};
    }

    std::vector<double> result(lhs.size());

    std::transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), 
                   [](double lhs, double rhs) {return lhs - rhs;});
}
```

Think in a higher level, otherwise there is no point in using C++. Efficient abstractions are signature difference between C and C++.

Comment: I tried return std::vector<double>{}; but I had a warning on Eclipse. @Incomputable thank you for you code. I'm a beginner in C++ and I do things step by step. What I did is creating  a vector of size 0: std::vector<double> result(0); and in my if condition I returned result and the compilation went fine. Once I have mastered the exceptions I will start using them.

Comment: @mja, you can just write `return {}`. Compiler will understand what you mean, because it knows the return type. Also, you won't get any benefit from answering after 4-5 days compared to answering immediately.

Comment: my compiler gave me a warning when I used `return {}`. I stick to what I mentionned above. Thank you.

Comment: @mja, what exactly it said? It shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: it said this `attention : extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

Comment: @mja, well, they should've been enabled anyway. Add `-std=c++14` to your compiler flags, if you're not running on something ancient. In general, today I would strongly encourage to not learn ancient C++-03 today.